# Laravel - Duplicated Routes

Tags: laravel-5, routes

in my case i have created two **Routes** like this :

> Route 1: `Route::get('/{title}',[
>               'as' => 'projects',
>               'uses' => 'FrontendController@show'
>   ]);`
>
> Route 2: `Route::get('/test', function (){
>       return 'Route test';
>   });`

then when i try to **redirect** at **Route 2** :

> http://localhost:8000/test

i get the **same result** of **Route 1**. He take **/test** like param for the **Route 1** but /test is another **Route**. Any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move route 2 above route 1. Route 1 will attempt to bind to the {title} parameter anything that potentially matches. Your routes file should look like this:

```
Route::get('/test', function (){
    return 'Route test';
});

Route::get('/{title}',[
    'as' => 'projects',
    'uses' => 'FrontendController@show'
]);
```

This way /test will be matched before /{title} has an opportunity to consume it.